# React Native (React Navigation) Passing data from one screen to another using

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I have a react native application that I created using `Ignite CLI`. I am trying to use TabNavigator with React Navigation, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass data from one screen to another. All the examples I've seen generally show how to pass the data when tapping on a button and using the `onPress` function, but in my case I need/want to pass the data when I actually tap one of the tab buttons, and I have yet to find an explanation on how to do this, at least one that I understand.

I have two screens that the user will interact with `SearchScreen` and `WatchScreen`. The two screens are controlled by the TabNavigator which is in an `AppNavigation.js` file. So there are a total of 3 files `AppNavigation.js`, `SearchScreen.js` and `WatchScreen.js`.

`AppNavigation.js`

```
import { StackNavigator,TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import SearchScreen from '../Containers/SearchScreen'
import WatchScreen from '../Containers/WatchScreen'
import SearchWatch from '../Containers/SearchWatch'
import LaunchScreen from '../Containers/LaunchScreen'
import styles from './Styles/NavigationStyles'

const PrimaryNav = TabNavigator({
  Search: { screen: SearchScreen },
  Watch: { screen: WatchScreen }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Search',
  lazy: true,

})
export default PrimaryNav
```

The `SearchScreen` will fetch some data and hold it in an array, that I need to be available in the `WatchScreen` as well. Generally I would pass data to the WatchScreen as a prop, but using the TabNavigator I can't see how to do this, since it's not a child of `SearchScreen`. In `SearchScreen the relevant piece is this

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = { movies: []}
}
```

`this.state.movies` is what I need to be available in my `WatchScreen`, how can I make this so it's available when I tap the `Watch` button in the tab bar?

Things I've read indicate that every `Screen` Component gets passed navigation props in either the form of `this.props.navigation` or `this.props.screenProps`, would this be how I would pass the `movies` array to my `WatchScreen`? If so,`this.props.navigation` & `this.props.screenProps` don't appear to be getting passed to my WatchScreen.

Comment: You may need to use redux , there is no other solution

Answer (score 6):

Sending data

```
 onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(
                SCREEN_NAME,
                {
                    item: YOUR_DATA_WHAT_YOU_NEDD_TO_SEND
                }
            )}
```

Receiving Data

```
  const item = this.props.navigation.getParam('item');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but the `onPress` prop works with a `<Button>` component, the issue I have is I  am not using a `<Button>` component to change tabs, I am using the actual "button" the Tab bar creates which as far as I can tell does not take an `onPress` prop.

For now I've just created a property on the `window` object so I can access what I need in my second tab/screen.